# Reshape a dataframe with X1, Y1,X2,Y2 to X, Y1, Y2 in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2

I have a dataframe `df` with XY combinations as follows

```
> df <- data.frame(X1=c(1:4),Y1=c(16:13),X2=c(4:7),Y2=c(-1:-4))
> df
  X1 Y1 X2 Y2
1  1 16  4 -1
2  2 15  5 -2
3  3 14  6 -3
4  4 13  7 -4
```

and want to reshape `df`to `df2`by merging `X1` and `X2`to a new variable `X` adding `NA` where `Y1` or `Y2` is left without value.

The result would look like this

```
> df2
  X  Y1  Y2
1 1  16  NA
2 2  15  NA
3 3  14  NA
4 4  13  -1
5 5  NA  -2
6 6  NA  -3
7 7  NA  -4
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::full_join`:

```
df2 <- dplyr::full_join(df[, c("X1", "Y1")], df[, c("X2", "Y2")], by = c("X1" = "X2"))
names(df2)[1] <- "X"
df2
#  X Y1 Y2
#1 1 16 NA
#2 2 15 NA
#3 3 14 NA
#4 4 13 -1
#5 5 NA -2
#6 6 NA -3
#7 7 NA -4
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `merge` from `base R`

```
merge(df[c('X1', 'Y1')], df[c('X2', 'Y2')], by.x = 'X1', by.y = 'X2', all = TRUE)
```